# Java Calendar not displaying right infomation

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a program that adds to a variable if its not a weekend or a holiday (stored in a txt file).
My code is saying it is a weekend even though it is not and I am very confused. Anything will help thanks!

**Code**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int day = 0;
    while (true) {

      // Gets current date
      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
      cal.add(cal.DATE, day);
      SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
      String formatted = format.format(cal.getTime());

      System.out.println("\nDate: " + formatted);

      try {
        // If its Saturday or Sunday
        if (cal.DAY_OF_WEEK == Calendar.SATURDAY || cal.DAY_OF_WEEK == Calendar.SUNDAY) {
          System.out.println("Weekend");
          System.exit(0);
        }   
        else {
          // Opens the dates.txt
          BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("dates.txt"));
          String line  = reader.readLine(); // The current line

          // Loops through the file until end
          while (line != null) {            
            if (line == formatted)// If holiday is current day {
              System.out.println("Holiday");
              System.exit(0);
            }
            line = reader.readLine();   // Goes to the next line
          }
          System.out.println("School");
          day += 1;
        }
      }    
      catch(FileNotFoundException e){}
      catch(IOException e){}

      try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
      } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: Sleep Failed");
      }
      day ++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: use `equals()` to compare `String`'s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
if (cal.DAY_OF_WEEK == Calendar.SATURDAY || cal.DAY_OF_WEEK == Calendar.SUNDAY)
```

`cal.DAY_OF_WEEK` is **not** the current day of the week that the calendar is set to, it is a constant that is to be used with the `get` method to get the current day of the week:

```
if (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SATURDAY || cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the properties in a wrong way:

```
  if (cal.get(Calendar.Day_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SATURDAY || cal.get(Calendar.Day_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY){
                System.out.println("Weekend");
                System.exit(0);
            }
```

See the [Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html):

> DAY_OF_WEEK  Field number for get and set indicating the day of the
>   week.